# Unable excel to solve formulars over vb.net (Error: HRESULT: 0x800A03EC)

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, excel-interop

I'm working on a little task which do no more than copy the data from the SQL-Database to Excel. For one Workbook I get the Error : HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
My intuition tells me that in that cell Excel trys to solve a Formula because of the characters he gets from the Database. How do I unable excel to Solve formulars from vb.net and tell him just to copy the data he gets?

The problem should be here:

```
For Each dr In Table.Rows
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 0
                    For Each dc In Table.Columns
                        colIndex += 1
                        '08/2016 MM Byte[] können nicht in Excel exportiert werden
                        If Not System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]").Equals(dr(dc.ColumnName).GetType) Then
                            oWS.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)


                        Else
                            oWS.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString

                        End If

                    Next
```

Any held would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you put a `'` before the data?

Comment: Thanks man, I figured it as well but I thought it was because excel was doing calculations that it should't. After being sure it was a huge String with loads of characters he was trying to copy in I just changed the code a bit and it worked! Thanks again @theBugger

Comment: Good for you. Maybe add an answer explaining how you solved

Answer (score 0):

Solved it guys, just compare the code above and this one:

```
For Each dr In Table.Rows
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 0
                    For Each dc In Table.Columns
                        colIndex += 1

                        If Not System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]").Equals(dr(dc.ColumnName).GetType) Then
                            Try
                                oWS.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                If System.Type.GetType("System.String").Equals(dr(dc.ColumnName).GetType) Then
                                    oWS.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = """" + dr(dc.ColumnName) + """"
                                Else
                                    'Exception konnte nicht aufgelöst werden, weiter werfen
                                    Throw ex
                                End If
                            End Try

                        Else
                            oWS.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString

                        End If

                    Next
                Next
```